# Updating a value in PostgreSQL from Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, post, leaflet

I want to update a value of a cell in PostgreSQL from a Leaflet popup. 
What I am trying to do is run a javascript function when the submit button within a form is pressed, and thereafter sending the value that has been typed in to the form, via a PHP script called from within the javascript function, to the PostgreSQL database.

This is what my popup function is looking like with its form.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    insertsearch = feature.properties.gid

    popUpText = "<b>Name</b>:    " + feature.properties.businessna + 
    "<br> <b>Address: </b>" + feature.properties.addresslin + ",  " + feature.properties.addressl_1 +
    "<br><b>Food hygiene rating</b> <span id=skala>(1-5)</span> : " + feature.properties.ratingvalu +
    "<form id='formoid' action='javascript:insertdata();'><br>Rating (between 1 and 5): <input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' max='5'><input type='submit'></form>"
    feature.properties.gid;

    feature.properties.popupContent = popUpText;
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
};
```

Here is the PHP script i want to use: (**insert.php**)

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$conn_str = "host=localhost dbname=geoweb 
   user=user password=user";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_str) 
  or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


//innumber is supposed to be the rating value given by the user in the HTML   form 
$innumber=;

//idnumber is supposed to be the GID of the point that is being rated
//GID is this variable in the HTML function (insertsearch =  feature.properties.gid)
$idnumber=;

//norate is the NUMBER OF TIMES the place has been rated
$norate= pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT rate FROM rating WHERE gid=$idnumber");

//findnumber is getting THE RATING value that the place already has
$findnumber= pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT rateav FROM rating WHERE gid=$idnumber");

//newvalue adds the existing rating value to the users new rating
$newvalue= $innumber + $findnumber;

//adds on 1 (one) to the norate to update how many times the place has been rated
$newcount= $norate+1;

//the query is updating the new rating value of the place. 
//It replaces the old rating value with the a new value
$query="UPDATE rating SET rateav=$newvalue, rate=$newcount  WHERE gid=$idnumber";
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);

pg_freeresult($result);  
pg_close($dbconn);

?>
```

My problem is now figuring out how to write the javascript function. As I understand it i should use a jquery $post method to send the data via the **insert.php** script. Howver, am i supposed to send parameters to the JS function in the HTML form (action=...)? If so, how do i do it?
I am trying to send two values via the PHP script, that is the *insertsearch* variable in the popup function (to get the correct entry in the table), and the rating number given by the user in the form.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `.ajax` with the `data` option filled with whatever parameters you need to perform this POST. Make sure to specify the URL, dataType, and method as well, alongside data.